# Access an XSLT file as resource from same project?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, xslt

I have an XSLT file that I want to load and use to transform an XML file. I've added the file to the same project as the code that uses it and put it in the "Resources" folder and set the Build Action to "Resource".

This is the code that tries to access the file:

```
        XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

        myXslTransform.Load(@"[projectName];component/Resources/OrderManagement/OrderOverview.xslt");
```

... where [projectName] is the name of the project. However this doesn't seem to work. I've played around with different paths, but somehow I don't seem to get it right. I'm sure it's just a little thing, but none of the articles I have found on the internet (or here) have helped me.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A co-worker has helped me find a solution. We added the resource via the properties of the project, so that I can access its content easily and used the following code.

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(Resources.OrderOverview)) {
  using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader)) {
    myXslTransform.Load(xmlReader);
    myXslTransform.Transform(fileName, arguments, xmlTextWriter);
  }
}
```

This is very similar to what outcoldman suggested with the subtle difference that the resource is accessed differently.

Answer (score 5):

Change the build action from Resource to Embedded Resource, after this you can do something like

```
XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

var assembly = typeof(SomeTypeFromAssemblyWithResource).Assembly;
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Resources.OrderManagement.OrderOverview.xslt"))
{
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        myXslTransform.Load(xmlReader );
    }
}
```

Resource name in dll can be tricky so maybe you want first to know the resource name with [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx). Compiler generates name based on the folder and assembly.

Comment: I have tried this with no success so far, but will see if I can get it to work tomorrow.

Comment: Yep, let me know if you will stuck. I wrote this from my head, so this code can have bugs.