# How to refer to included file inside a visual studio project c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xslt

I have a window form project that use a XSL file to convert a XML file.

When I call the XSL file I use a specific method and I pass it the XML's path:

```
myXslTransform.Load("...\\Trasformazione.xsl");
```

How can I refer to the file included in my project? Because when I publish it the other people don't have the same path and the program does not work.

> For example:
>
> ```
> myXslTransform.Load("MyProject.Trasformazione.xsl");
> ```

Comment: So where do you store the XML and/or the XSLT when you deploy your program? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302284.aspx might help.

Comment: Is the XSLT simply a content file, or is it am embedded resource in the project? If it is an embedded resource, this link may help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883598/access-an-xslt-file-as-resource-from-same-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the path in App.config

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FilePath" value="...\\MyProject.Trasformazione.xsl" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And in Code:

```
myXslTransform.Load(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FilePath"));
```

The other people needs to edit config-File (AppName.exe.Config)