# How to get XSLT file copied to bin in visual studio for a C# app for XslCompiledTransform.Load()

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xslt

I'm trying to process a bunch of XML files and correct the data in them in them so they are on the correct version and my XSLT file is a reference and set to always be copied, but it isn't being added to the bin folder. How do I correct it so my XSLT file is added to bin for use in the `XslCompiledTransform.Load()` method or is there a different method I should be utilizing?

```
string destinationFile = fileItem.FileLocation.Substring(0, fileItem.FileLocation.Length - fileItem.FileName.Length) + "working_" + fileItem.FileName;

XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(destinationFile);

XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTrans.Load("TwentyNineteenPointTwoDowngrade.xslt");
```

EDIT: Needed to be an embedded resource to have be included in the folder structure

Alternatively the next step was similar in nature as the following  access of the resource referenced from : [Access an XSLT file as resource from same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883598/access-an-xslt-file-as-resource-from-same-project)

Comment: Add file to project by using Solution explorer and right click where modules are shown and select Add Existing item and browse for file.  Then right click object and select copy to bin folder.

Comment: Jdweng , the file is already in the project  and listed as a "Resource " for it's build action with "Copy Always" for the  Copy to Output directory. This is why I'm confused why it isn't copying over or if this is even the proper methodology to use for this type of file or do I need to add it as a DLL resource instead and have it loaded through the XslCompiledTransform.Load() through something else.

Comment: You didn't look at my 2nd step.  Go to solution explorer and right click resource.  Then select properties.  Change DO NOT COPY

Comment: @jdweng I think I caught on. I clicked the project , right click accessed it's properties and went to resources, but the access to resources no longer exists there and is now apparently in a RESX file. under the properties folder of the project. default name being Resources.resx .

Answer (score 0):

Resource to include the file itself it needed to be  **Embedded Resource** under the build action.